# iOS Can't get Dictionary values to an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have dictionary:

```
{
6 =     (
            {
        id = 6;
        name = Andrea;
    },
            {
        id = 6;
        name = Paolo;
    }
);
8 =     (
            {
        id = 8;
        name = Maria;
    }
);
67 =     (
            {
        id = 67;
        name = Francesco;
    },
            {
        id = 67;
        name = Sara;
    }
);
}
```

I tried to get Values to array.

My code is:

```
 NSArray *arrayNew= [result valueForKey:@"67"];

NSLog(@"Hello:%@",arrayNew);
```

But Always i got null value.

My complete code:

```
   NSMutableArray *idArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File"
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];

NSMutableData *results11 = [content JSONValue];

NSLog(@"Check:%@",results11);

NSArray *array= [results11 valueForKeyPath:@"field"];





NSMutableDictionary* result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary* dict in array)
{
    NSNumber* anID = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];


    if (![idArray containsObject:[dict objectForKey:@"id"]]) {
        // do something

         [idArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"id"]];

    }






    NSMutableArray* resultsForID = [result objectForKey:anID];

    if (!resultsForID)
    {
        resultsForID = [NSMutableArray array];
        [result setObject:resultsForID forKey:anID];
    }

    [resultsForID addObject:dict];


}

NSLog(@"Result:%@",result);
NSLog(@"ID arr:%@",idArray);

 //   NSArray *temp= [results11 valueForKeyPath:@"Response.alertHistory"];




NSString *arrayNew= [result valueForKeyPath:@"67"];

NSLog(@"Hello:%@",arrayNew);
```

File.txt : `{
"field": [
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Andrea"
},
{
"id": 67,
"name": "Francesco"
},
{
"id": 8,
"name": "Maria"
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Paolo"
},
{
"id": 67,
"name": "Sara"
}
]
}`

Comment: can u show some additional code

Comment: Try this: `NSArray *arrayNew = (NSArray *)result[@"67"];`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Now i added complete code.

Comment: @PhamHoan No working. please check my completed code.

Comment: @matt its displaying (null)

Comment: Can u show the result of `NSLog(@"Result:%@",result);
NSLog(@"ID arr:%@",idArray);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally with reference of Tommy's solution I solved my issue.

```
NSArray *commentArray = result[@67];
```

And my final code:

```
 NSMutableArray *idArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File"
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];

NSMutableData *results11 = [content JSONValue];

NSLog(@"Check:%@",results11);

NSArray *array= [results11 valueForKeyPath:@"field"];





NSMutableDictionary* result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary* dict in array)
{
    NSNumber* anID = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];


    if (![idArray containsObject:[dict objectForKey:@"id"]]) {
        // do something

         [idArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"id"]];

    }






    NSMutableArray* resultsForID = [result objectForKey:anID];

    if (!resultsForID)
    {
        resultsForID = [NSMutableArray array];
        [result setObject:resultsForID forKey:anID];
    }

    [resultsForID addObject:dict];


}

NSLog(@"Result:%@",result);





NSMutableArray *arrayNew = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];




for (int i=0; i<[idArray count]; i++) {

    NSArray *commentArray = result[idArray[i]];


    NSLog(@"COMM:%@",commentArray);


    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary* dict in commentArray)
    {
        [arr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }


    [arrayNew addObject:arr];
}


NSLog(@"ID arr:%@",idArray);
NSLog(@"Name arr:%@",arrayNew);
```

**File.txt :**

```
{
"field": [
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Andrea"
},
{
"id": 67,
"name": "Francesco"
},
{
"id": 8,
"name": "Maria"
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Paolo"
},
{
"id": 67,
"name": "Sara"
}
]
}
```

My final result:

```
ID arr:(
6,
67,
8
)

 Name arr:(
        (
        Andrea,
        Paolo
    ),
        (
        Francesco,
        Sara
    ),
        (
        Maria
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason for this is that your `NSDictionary` uses integers, not `NSString`s, as its keys. In this case this should work:

```
NSArray *arrayNew= [result objectForKey:@67]; // No quotes
```

Comment: Its crashing. [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b649470

Comment: @PREMKUMAR Can you try `objectForKey` instead?

Comment: ... or even `result[@67]`. But take the implied point: if you don't know the difference between the two, you definitely don't want `valueForKey:`.

Comment: @Tommy great your answer is finally helped.

Comment: @PREMKUMAR There should be zero difference between `result[@67]` and `[result objectForKey:@67]`, because one calls the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayNew = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *commentArray = [dictionary valueForKey:@"67"];
for (NSDictionary *commentDic in commentArray) {

                Model *modelObj = [[Model alloc] init];   
                modelObj = [Model modelFromDictionary:commentDic];
                [arrayNew addObject:modelObj]
        }
```

Also you will have to create Model .h and .m class to do the mapping.
and modelFromDictionary method will do the mapping.

.m

```
@implementation Version

- (NSDictionary *)jsonMapping {

return [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"id",@"id",
        @"name",@"name",
        nil];
}

+ (Model *)modelFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

Model *model = [[Model alloc] init];

NSDictionary *mapping = [model jsonMapping];

for(NSString *attribute in [mapping allKeys]) {

    NSString *classProperty = [mapping objectForKey:attribute];
    NSString *attributeValue = [dictionary objectForKey:attribute];

    if(attributeValue != nil && ![attributeValue isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

        [model setValue:attributeValue
                 forKey:classProperty];
    }

}
return model;
}
```

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;



+ (Model *)modelFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
```

Comment: can you send model.h and model.m file?